# Master Page in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

I want to customize my master page of share point 2013 so I copy my default master page(Seattle.master) then i open the copy but sharepoint designer 2013 not responding
what should i do or what is my mistake??

Comment: check this http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2013/02/issue-with-creating-copy-of.html

Comment: Thank you for this link but the main problem is I copy seattle.master in share point designer 2013 and I customize the copy but the size of my customized master file go so larger than the main(1.5 mega byte) with many enters beside of it I've no idea what happened